# how to add a javascript plugin to vaadin website

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to add a web plugin to my Vaadin website.  Normally for such plugins, you add a JavaScript snippet to the `<body>` or `<head>` sections (depending on the plugin), but we don't have access to that directly in Vaadin development, so was wondering how people do it?

Maybe this is where we use `@JavaScript` annotation, referenced [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/articles/IntegratingAJavaScriptComponent.html#integrating-a-javascript-component), but that seems like overkill since I don't think I need a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JavaScript` can be used to load any JavaScript file, it doesn't need to be a component.

Comment: When I did this, I see it in the `<head>` section, but my website does not change and I don't see it in the "sources" in the browser.  Any hints on why?