# pendo or similar service inside Vaadin app

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

How do people use [pendo](https://www.pendo.io/) inside a Vaadin 7 application? I know of the following things that need to be done, with my current pendo knowledge:

1. Embed pendo JavaScript snippet on every page. So, since most Vaadin apps are single page apps, I guess this snippet needs to be loaded in UI, maybe using `Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute` or `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute`. I think there is also a `@JavaScript` annotation, but I have tried that a few times and could not get it to work (see [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18363995/referencing-javascript-with-javascript-annotation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961073/how-to-add-a-javascript-plugin-to-vaadin-website) for one place where I could not get it to work).
2. Initialize pendo by calling pendo.initialize({...});. I guess this needs to be done after logging into my application (so have user id at this point) via `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute`, but not entirely sure where to do this. Also, according to Pendo, it needs to be done on every windows reload. I guess I could do this in my UI class, only occurring after login is complete. But do I also need to do it when going between views? That is not, strictly speaking, a reload, so just not sure.

Basically, I figure someone out there has used Pendo in a Vaadin application, so looking for any advice I can get, especially advice that is not included already in the pendo documentation.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

1. Based on the fact that this is a single page app, I followed the directions [here](https://support.pendo.io/hc/en-us/articles/360031862272-Installation-for-Single-Page-Frameworks#YourInstallationSnippet) and [here](https://support.pendo.io/hc/en-us/articles/360022819711-Snippet-Install#Step3InstallthePendoJavaScriptSnippet), and created a `pendo.js` script in my resources directory.  This script only has the "Part 1 of Snippet" from the first link, and obviously I got rid of `<script>` and `</script>`, since I put it in a file by itself.
2. In my UI class, I added `@com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript("pendo.js")`
3. After logging in, I run `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(pendoInitialization);`, where "pendoInitialization" is visitor and account information as requested in the first link above, in my case something like `pendo.initialize({visitor: {id: 'VDR_JCARROS'}, account: {id: 'VEEDER'}});`.

This seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have direct experience with Pendo, but with a similar product called WalkMe (https://www.walkme.com/). In order to add this to the page we did the following

1. Create a custom implementation of the `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet`
2. Override `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet#servletInitialized`, here we do the following

```java
@Override
    public void servletInitialized () throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized ();

        getService ().addSessionInitListener ( new SessionInitListener () {

            @Override
            public void sessionInit ( SessionInitEvent event ) throws ServiceException {

                event.getSession ().addBootstrapListener ( new BootstrapListener () {

                    @Override
                    public void modifyBootstrapFragment ( BootstrapFragmentResponse response ) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void modifyBootstrapPage ( BootstrapPageResponse response ) {

                        if ( scripts.length != 0 ) {
                            ArrayUtils.reverse ( scripts );
                            for ( String script: scripts ) {
                                if ( !script.isEmpty () ) {
                                    response.getDocument ().head ().prependElement ( "script" ).attr ( "type", "text/javascript" ).text ( script );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
    }
```

- The scripts to be prepended to the header are based into the custom servlet implementation via the constructor

3. Register the CustomServlet as a bean of type VaadinServlet using a class annotated with @Configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class VaadinConfig {

    @Bean
    public VaadinServlet getVaadinServlet () {
        return new CustomServlet ( new String [] { "The actual WalkMeScript" } );
    }


}
```

In order for WalkMe to realize the which page it is on and which item to highlight next we introduced ids on every relevant Vaadin component and these are then used in the WalkMe scripts

P.S. It's worth mentioning that we are using Spring Boot, so how to register the Servlet may be different for you depending on your stack